# Comparing numbers digit by digit

Tags: c++

I want to write a function that compares the numbers in an array and deletes those who contain the same digits (ex. 1335 531) .The deleting part arouses no problems but I can't seem to figure out how to compare them digit by digit, especially when they don't have the same length. Any idea is more that welcomed and appreciated.

Comment: Hint: There's a `std::unique` algorithm.

Comment: I'd use `std::to_string` to convert the integer to string, then compare the digits.

Answer (score 3):

```
 unsigned get_digit_mask(unsigned input) 
 {
     unsigned result = 0;
     unsigned digit;
     do {
         digit = input%10; //get the rightmost digit
         input/=10; //remove it from the number
         result |= (1<<digit); //set that bit of the result
     }while(input); //continue as long as there's more digits
     return result; //return bitmask of used digits
 }
```

If you use this function on the number 1335, it will return a mask with the 1st, 3rd, and 5th bits set.  If you give the function the number 531, it will return a mask with the 1st, 3rd, and 5th bits set.  If the masks are equal, then the numbers contain the same digits.

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking of. Works perfectly!

Comment: it does?  I'm surprised actually, I didn't even test it